# What causes the error "FilteredElementCollector_constructor or one item in the collection is null at line 326 of file" when running revit addin?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have recently begun the task of converting a dynamo node i made in c# to an addin. But when i click the button to run the method it returns the command failure as shown in the image. I have tried to find some info on why this might happen, but i haven't been able to find anything helpful.

```
class App : IExternalApplication
    {
        


        static void AddRibbonPanel(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            //Create a custom ribbon tab
            String tabname = "Krüger Addins";
            application.CreateRibbonTab(tabname);

            //Add a new ribbon panel
            RibbonPanel ribbonPanel = application.CreateRibbonPanel(tabname, "Tools");

            //Get dll assembly path
            string thisAssemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

            //Create push button for ISO_KRG
            PushButtonData b1data = new PushButtonData(
                "ISO Generator",
                "ISO Generator",
                thisAssemblyPath,
                "ISO_KRG.ISO_KRG");

            PushButton pb1 = ribbonPanel.AddItem(b1data) as PushButton;
            pb1.ToolTip = "Pick middle line of the bends";
            BitmapImage pb1Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ISO_KRG;component/Resources/KrugerLogo.ico"));
            pb1.LargeImage = pb1Image;


        }

        public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            // do nothing
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            // call our method that will load up our toolbar
            AddRibbonPanel(application);
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
```

```
Result IExternalCommand.Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        Autodesk.Revit.DB.Document docu = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
        

        


        IsoGeneratorV2(doc);

        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkmOX.png)

I tried just running it and i think it might have something to do with the Autodesk.Revit.DB.Document i use in my methods versus when executing the code in the IExternalApplication.
EDIT: I realised the error occurs in IExternalCommand.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so, i figured out that i had to use docu in the ENTIRE method instead of any "Autodesk.Revit.DB.Document doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument;" i might have used.